# Should I contest this right on red traffic violation

Tags: usa, car-rentals, traffic, delaware

I received a violation notice from the rental car agency for a red light violation. Here's the [video](http://www.public.cite-web.com/citeweb3/PlayFLV.asp?vFile=/media/Wilmington/Images/2016/07/Dep_194612/20160729_122603_7274_000007.flv).

<strike>Here's</strike><sup>*</sup> a still [image](http://www.public.cite-web.com/PublicINQ/ShowImage.asp?vFile=/media/Wilmington/Images/2016/07/dep_194612/07292016_122603_7274_4_13_7_1I1.jpg%20&vImageLable=Digital%20Photo%201&vCitNum=565960) <strike>too, that</strike> shows my brake lights before the turn.

Can I contest this? It clearly shows that there was no traffic, I breaked came to a stop and turned right. I'm not aware of specific laws in Delaware but I thought that it was legal to make a right on red like most other states.

The fine is $110.

**Update**:
It appears that it was [illegal for Wilmington](http://6abc.com/news/wilmington-refunding-over-$800k-ends-right-turn-on-red-cameras/1811460/) to be ticketing people who made a right on red this way and I'm getting a refund.

<sup>* Link is dead</sup>

Comment: What is there to contest? You didn't come to a complete stop, but 'rolled' through the red light. Whether there's traffic or not is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about travel.

Comment: Right-on-red is legal in Delaware, and everywhere in the USA other than New York City. (The general rule can be overridden by a specific sign.) In your case, it can be hard to judge from a video, but it looks far from a complete stop. When I lived on the East Coast (up to 1981), Delaware was known for strict traffic law enforcement.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus thanks for your input, I've added a link to a still image as well. As advice would you reckon that this is worth contesting or chalking this off as a life lesson and paying up.

Comment: What is the citation for? Not stopping on the turn? It's quite clear from the video that you certainly didn't stop.

Comment: The citation is for a `Red Light Violation`

Comment: Braking ≠ stopping. Your brake lights just showed that you slowed down. Also, to the extent that you stopped at all, you were well over the big white line before you did, so even if the stop is sufficient, it wasn't before the line. I would just pay up. See e.g. http://www.delawareonline.com/story/news/traffic/burke/2014/09/12/red-light-cameras-money-safety/15529689/ for some local discussion.

Comment: Thank for the link to the local discussion, doesn't look like I've got much of a case here. I'll delete the question if you guys think it's not relevant to this forum and unlikely to help someone else.

Comment: The still image does not help, because it cannot show whether you actually stopped. The first time I played the video there was a pause that looked like a stop, but that was just buffering. The second and subsequent times I played it in quick succession the car rolled smoothly through the lights, slowing, with brake lights on, but never stopping.

Comment: https://www.google.com/maps/@39.7524312,-75.5563006,3a,75y,341.4h,77.87t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sLQjY5tmDY95IHfvA1CDEoQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656 - google streetmap image showing the sign "stop here on red" with a camera image on it

Comment: Wow @Berwyn how did you find the exact intersection so quickly?

Comment: Deleting this, I guess @chx is correct, this isn't related to travel and it's too specific to help anyone else. Thanks for chiming in fellows. This is a good lesson for me, will adhere to rules more strictly in new places. I suppose regardless of the move being safe, it's still not legal.

Comment: Just searched for Luther Towers

Comment: Was useful for me. I didn't know you had to stop before turning right on red...

Comment: The question may be useful to remind people who are not used to right-turn-on-red that it does require a complete stop, not just slowing. Travelers, especially from outside the US, may not be aware of that.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll leave this be then. Maybe someone else can learn from my mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right Turn on Red is allowed in all 50 states and all provinces and territories of Canada. The cities of New York and Montreal, however, specifically disallow it unless there is an explicit sign allowing it. In all other places it is allowed unless there is a sign disallowing it.

The  rules for "Right Turn on Red"  are the following:

- The car must come to a complete stop.
- The stop must be behind the broad white line or any sign explicitly saying "Stop Here on Red".

A complete stop means the wheels must stop moving. Braking and slowing down even to 1 mph isn't the same as stopping. Although there is no fixed amount of time you must be stopped for, many people use 3 seconds as a rule of thumb to be sure.

The stop *must* happen, no matter how much or how little traffic there is, before you can proceed with the right turn.

In your case, your video clearly shows that you *didn't* come to a complete stop, and you were well past the white line when you slowed to your slowest. Stopping past the line is much more likely to get you a ticket from a Red Light Camera than from an actual police officer.

Here's some local discussion of Red Light cameras in Delaware:

- http://www.delawareonline.com/story/news/traffic/burke/2014/09/12/red-light-cameras-money-safety/15529689/

And here's a Google streetmap image showing that there is an explicit "Stop Here on Red" sign at the intersection:

- https://www.google.com/maps/@39.7524312,-75.5563006,3a,75y,341.4h,77.87t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sLQjY5tmDY95IHfvA1CDEoQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656

Comment: It is important for travelers to remember that enforcement varies from place to place. A slowing without completely stopping might not be noticed in one location, but would get a ticket in other locations.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Given that there are no places in which rolling stops are legal, it seems unwise to make any suggestions that one might get away with it. Whereas with speeding there are definitely enforcement patterns that vary from state to state or city to city, I think this kind of ticket is much more likely to have a relatively consistent enforcement. And with red light cameras even more so.

Comment: I think it would be better if everyone came to a complete stop before any right turn on red, anywhere. That both conforms to the law, and is safer than rolling into the intersection. The problem I'm seeing is that the OP seemed to think that braking was enough, without actually stopping. It may be that in the OP's home area there are no red light cameras and the police are lax about rolling stops. Then the OP drove in an area with red light cameras...